# How to split a series by the longest repetition of a number in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label':[f"subj_{i}" for i in range(28)],
    'data':[i for i in range(1, 14)] + [1,0,0,0,2] + [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
})
```

I have a dataset something like that. It looks like:

[image]

I want to cut it at where the longest repetitions of 0s occur, so I want to cut at index 18, but I want to leave index 14-16 intact. So far I've tried stuff like:

- Counters

```
cad_recorder = 0
new_index = []
for i,row in tqdm(temp_df.iterrows()):
    if row['cadence'] == 0:
        cad_recorder += 1
        new_index.append(i)
```

```
* But obviously that won't work since the indices will be rewritten at each occurrance of zero.
```

- I also tried a dictionary, but I'm not sure how to compare previous and next values using iterrows.
- I also took the rolling mean for X rows at a time, and if its zero then I got an index. But then I got stuck at actually inferring the range of indices. Or finding the longest sequence of zeroes.

Edit: A friend of mine suggested the following logic, which gave the same results as @shubham-sharma. The poster's solution is much more pythonic and elegant.

```py
def find_longest_zeroes(df):
    '''
    Finds the index at which the longest reptitions of <1 values begin
    '''
    current_length = 0
    max_length = 0
    start_idx = 0
    max_idx = 0


    for i in range(len(df['data'])):
        if df.iloc[i,9] <= 1:
            if current_length == 0:
                start_idx = i
            current_length += 1

            if current_length > max_length:
                max_length = current_length
                max_idx = start_idx
        else:
            current_length = 0
    return max_idx
```

The code I went with following @shubham-sharma's solution:

```py
cut_us_sof = {}
og_df_sof = pd.DataFrame()
cut_df_sof = pd.DataFrame()

for lab in df['label'].unique():
    temp_df = df[df['label'] == lab].reset_index(drop=True)
    mask = temp_df['data'] <= 1 # some values in actual dataset were 0.0000001
    counts = temp_df[mask].groupby((~mask).cumsum()).transform('count')['data']
    idx = counts.idxmax()
    # my dataset's trailing zeroes are usually after 200th index. But I also didn't want to remove trailing zeroes < 500 in length
    if (idx > 2000) & (counts.loc[idx] > 500):
        cut_us_sof[lab] = idx
        og_df_sof = og_df_sof.append(temp_df)
        cut_df_sof = cut_df_sof.append(temp_df.iloc[:idx,:])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use boolean masking and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to identify the blocks of zeros, then `groupby` and `transform` these blocks using `count` followed by [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to get the starting index of the block having the maximum consecutive zeros

```
m = df['data'].eq(0)
idx = m[m].groupby((~m).cumsum()).transform('count').idxmax()
```

---

```
print(idx)

18
```

Comment: Amazing. I edited my OP with the code that we came up with, but this does the same thing in 2 lines. In a separate thread I would like to get your thoughts on why our code gets similar but different results.

I edited OP with the entire code using this solution for any future readers. Thanks @shubham-sharma!

Comment: @sc4s2cg Lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)